# why google mlkit barcode scanner scan the same barcode multiple times and even some part of it

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

i am using camerax and google mlkit barcode-scanning library to make a barcode reader. and the app scan qrcode is work fine, but the code format is barcode, the result will different. the barcode sometimes will scan multiple times for example, there are tree barcodes but the scanner get the four or five results.
anybody knows the issue and any help is appreciate.
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpEZZ.jpg)
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDM6O.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean there are three barcodes in a single image, and then it will return 4 or 5 results for it?

Comment: yes, one barcode may scan twice

Comment: Could you provide the image, so that we could take a look? Also, is the same barcode scanned twice? or is it identified as two barcode? To tell that, you could check whether the returned barcode information is duplicate or not.

Comment: ok, i will upload the image later. it's same barcode but  identified as two barcode and the value is partial of it

Comment: @Shiyu i have upload the screenshot of app, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think it's kind of expected. Due to the bias of image quality and barcode position, it's possible that part of the real barcode image is also identified as a barcode from the perspective of barcode detector.

Answer (score 0):

There really is nothing you can do about that, it just depends on the image/frame given to the analyzer. There are many factors that can effect the scanning of the barcode like light, angle of image/frame, image quality of the barcode, or quality of the barcode itself that can cause duplication to be found.

You will just need to have a way to remove ones that you dont want